# SharePoint 2013 - Content Type setup with an email notification

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have been exploring the use of creating custom "content types" and "columns" for lists in SharePoint 2013. I recently created a multi-choice drop down list for a column, for my announcements app. The drop down allows an administrator to mark if a project is assigned, pending, or completed.  But is there a away to extend this further, and also activate a notification message to someone (me or someone else), when my drop down is marked as "completed"?  Can I do this OOTB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly out of the box. There's an alerting option called "Someone changes an item that appears in the following view", you can set this view so it filters based on your drop down column. Once an item appears in this view (Because it's status is equal to Completed), it will automatically trigger.

There might be a feature you need to activate first that I don't remember out of my head, but the option definitely exists.

This is what it looks like:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/279175

Comment: That's awesome!  I will try to find this...thanks!

Comment: It looks like the ability to send email notifications for tasks has been removed from sharepoint 2013 - http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Enable-email-notifications-390a927c

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't the case, the last time I used this was in a 2013 Office 365 environment. Let me simulate your problem for a second and get back to you.

Comment: No need! I just found it.  From within my current Olso  template, if I enter into my Announcements or Tasks app, I can can see from the ribbon, there is an icon called "Alert Me".  It is under the list tab in the ribbon.  From there I can create/manage all alerts for applications I am running.  Thank you Chromanin!

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way you can do this OOTB. I too would love to know if there is. You can create a workflow to fire on the item edit. Which will check whether the status is 'Completed' every time and send an email if it is 'Completed'.

At very least, you can create a SharePoint Designer Workflow.

If you have the ability to write a VS Solution, I would recommend having an event receiver attached to the list on item update and send an email on completion rather creating a workflow.

Comment: As Chromanin say, if the alert fulfills your notification then that is fine. But it will be just an alert with limited flexibility for customization.